# How to update multilevels embed array on mongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I use spring-data-mongo mongoTemplate to update embed document.
and following is my data model:

```
{
    "_id":"3KNAM390aENt",
    "field":"test001",
    "name":"001",
    "sort":0,
    "embedFields1":{
        "_id":"1",
        "field":"field1",
        "name":"name1",
        "limit":1,
        "canBeChange":true,
        "needAudit":false,
        "embedFields2":{
            "_id":"22",
            "field":"field22",
            "name":"name22",
            "limit":1,
            "canBeChange":true,
            "needAudit":false,
            "embedFields3":{
                "_id":"3",
                "field":"field3",
                "name":"name3",
                "limit":1,
                "canBeChange":true,
                "needAudit":false,
                "embedFields4":{
                    "_id":"4",
                    "field":"field4",
                    "name":"name4",
                    "limit":1,
                    "canBeChange":true,
                    "needAudit":false,
                    "embedFields5":{
                        "_id":"5",
                        "field":"field5",
                        "name":"name5",
                        "limit":1,
                        "canBeChange":true,
                        "needAudit":false,
                        "embedFields6":{
                            "_id":"66",
                            "field":"field66",
                            "name":"name66",
                            "limit":1,
                            "canBeChange":true,
                            "needAudit":false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to use $ to update the maching first embedFields1 ,
but how to update the embed embedFields2,embedFields3,embedFields4.......?

Answer (score 0):

To navigate your structure you can use a syntax like this:

"`firstlevel.secondlevel.thirdlevel`"

Meaning you could create a dynamic logic for creating that string and using it inside mongodb commands.

Example

*Find*

`db.your_collection.find({"embedFields1.embedFields2.embedFields3._id" : "2"})`

*Update*

```
db.your_collection.update({"embedFields1.embedFields2.embedFields3._id" : "3"} , {$set : {"embedFields1.embedFields2.embedFields3.name" : "test"}})
```

Comment: db.your_collection.update({"embedFields1.embedFields2.embedFields3._id" : "3"} , {$set : {"embedFields1.embedFields2.embedFields3.name" : "test"}})    this can not work    ;                                              the official document explain to use  db.getCollection('arbitratorField').update(
    {} , 
    {$set : {"embedFields.$[e1].embedFields.$[e2].name" : "test"}},
    {arrayFilters:[{'e1._id':'Wx3uzi'},{'e2._id':'vti7KT'}]}
)   but when i use it  ,return a error  : No array filter found for identifier 'e1' in path 'embedFields.$[e1].embedFields.$[e2].name'

Comment: The $ syntax is used to navigate an array structure. You don't have an array , you have a dictionary representation so you can go through your nested document without $. The query I posted has been executed on my machine with your document structure and it works. Let me know :)

Comment: I know why you can success , because I give the data model is not complete .  The complete data model is  the dictionary container array .

Comment: {"_id" : "3KNAM390aENt",
    "embedFields" : [{"_id" : "1","embedFields" : [ {"_id" : "2","field" : "field2"},  {"_id" : "22","field" : "field22"}]}, 
        {"_id" : "11","embedFields" : [{"_id" : "2","field" : "field2",}, {"_id" : "22","field" : "field22",}]}, 
        {"_id" : "Wx3uzi","embedFields" : [ { "_id" : "vti7KT","name" : "test 22 update"}, {"_id" : "MOVy1i","name" : "test 2222 update"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: I can use follow common to update document on mongo shell , but I don't know how  to use it with java  spring-data-mongo's mongoTemplate;                                                            db.getCollection('field').update(
    {_id:"3KNAM390aENt"} , 
    {$set : {"embedFields.$[e1].embedFields.$[e2].name" : "test"}},
    {arrayFilters:[{'e1._id':'Wx3uzi'},{'e2._id':'vti7KT'}]}
)

Comment: I understood was about the mongodb query , not related spring-data-mongo. I don't know that library.